# Models methods not detected by laravel in controller. Maybe a routing issue?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Due to my lack of experience with Laravel, I am having difficulty understanding why I can get the Post model variables but there are errors thrown when I try to call its methods. I don't know if it is a routing issue or not. This is based on a Laravel bootstrap starter site from [Laravel starter site](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site) The following error and RegisteredUserController are as followed.

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::url()
```

---

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->join('registered_posts' , 'posts.id' , '=' , 'registered_posts.post_id')->get();


        foreach($posts as &$post){
            echo $post->id; //works fine
            echo $post->url(); //breaks
            echo '<br>';
        }
```

Here is the post model

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class Post extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * Deletes a blog post and all
     * the associated comments.
     *
     * @return bool
     */

 protected $fillable = array('registered_post');

    public function delete()
    {
        // Delete the comments
        $this->comments()->delete();

        // Delete the blog post
        return parent::delete();
    }

    public function registered_post(){
        return $this->registered_post;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a formatted post content entry,
     * this ensures that line breaks are returned.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function content()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Get the post's author.
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the post's meta_description.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function meta_description()
    {
        return $this->meta_description;
    }

    /**
     * Get the post's meta_keywords.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function meta_keywords()
    {
        return $this->meta_keywords;
    }

    /**
     * Get the post's comments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }

    /**
     * Get the date the post was created.
     *
     * @param \Carbon|null $date
     * @return string
     */
    public function date($date=null)
    {
        if(is_null($date)) {
            $date = $this->created_at;
        }

        return String::date($date);
    }

    /**
     * Get the URL to the post.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function url()
    {
        return Url::to($this->slug);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the date of the blog post creation,
     * on a good and more readable format :)
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function created_at()
    {
        return $this->date($this->created_at);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the date of the blog post last update,
     * on a good and more readable format :)
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function updated_at()
    {
        return $this->date($this->updated_at);
    }

}
```

Here are also the routes that I am using as well

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'registered', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{


    # Admin Dashboard
    Route::post('registered', 'RegisteredUserController@getIndex');
    Route::controller('/', 'RegisteredUserController');
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: post controller and relevant part of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using the Query Builder but are expecting an Eloquent result. With `DB::table` your result will only consist of bare objects instead of models (with functions like `url()`)

You can try this instead

```
$posts = Post::join('registered_posts' , 'posts.id' , '=' , 'registered_posts.post_id')->get();
```

You may also want to define the registered posts as relationship and then load it like that

```
$posts = Post::with('registeredPosts')->get();
```